# how to join two tables and count occurrences some values?

Tags: sql, join, count

I am asking to for a help because I do not know SQL very well.

I need to join two tables and count occurrences some values from second table to achieve effect like statistics table which will have coluns:

Result Table:

- country varchar(20),
- site varchar(20),
- suspected_violation long,
- confirmed_violation long,
- confirmed_no_violation long,
- not_determined long,
- total long

My Result Table needs to have first two columns (contry and site) comes from first table "Violations" and next 5 columns which will contain numbers (count) of occurrences status_id in "Violations" in each of possible values of id from Status table.

Now I can upload image of table result what I want to achieve:
[image: Result Table]

So, I have existing two tables: Violations and Status.

Violations:

- id long,
- country varchar(20),
- site varchar(20),
- status_id long, <-- this is the id of status in Status table.
- ... other columns not important in this case

Status:

- id long,
- status long 
  Column "status" have values (1-4) which are mapped to string values: Suspected Violation (1), Confirmed Violation (2), Confirmed No Violation (3), Not Determined (4)

In result of my join is to have table which should contain columns:

- from Violations table: "Country" and "Site"
- from Status table: "Suspected Violation", "Confirmed Violation", "Confirmed No Violation", "Not Determined", "Total" (where this columns are counters of occurrences in Violation table).

My pseudo code and abstract try:

```
SELECT v.country, v.site, count(v.status_id == 1), count(v.status_id == 2), count(v.status_id == 3), count(v.status_id == 4)
FROM Violations v JOIN Status s 
ON v.status_id=s.id
GROUP BY v.country, v.site
```

Pleas help me to write correct sql query, because have big problem to do that.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Where's the *picture* you mentioned?

Comment: I cannot add picture because of stacoverflow reputation limitation. I've added my pseud code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
select v.country,
    v.site,
    SUM(case when s.id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(case when s.id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(case when s.id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(case when s.id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total
from violations v
inner join status s
    on v.status_id = s.id
group by v.country, v.site
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d188/1)

This can also be written without the `JOIN`:

```
select v.country,
    v.site,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total
from violations v
group by v.country, v.site
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d188/2)

Comment: May I ask what this `INNER JOIN` is here for?

Comment: @PM77-1 As you will notice I added a second query because the `INNER JOIN` is not needed, unless you want to use any of the `status` table data in the result.  In the first query, you can use `s.id` in the `CASE` expression instead of `v.status_id`

Comment: Thanks, your solution is really helpful for me not advanced in SQL!

Comment: What about using this query in hibernate? Is it possible? because right now i am getting error: unexpected token: Total_SuspectedViolations etc...

Comment: @Roman I would suggest posting a new question and including the correct tags on it, so you will get the right audience.

Comment: @bluefeet I am checking your solution with values from DB and I see that all values from 4 SUMs are always 0. why these sum function do not count occurrences correctly? COUNT(*) for Total is correct only..

Comment: @Roman Can you post some sample data in your original post?  Or even better create a sql fiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ - with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: @Roman See my edit, I just updated it with demos of how these will work -- here is the demo link -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d188/3

Comment: here is my demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb466/1/0 I see you also create one. It seems that you're right but for some reason from my local Oracle DB this query cause in result only zeros for these SUM functions

Comment: @bluefeet Do you have an idea how to improve your SQL query to achieve result table like at attached picture? I mean there is missing three issues:
- "All" which should count occurrences for all countries
- "Unknown" which should count occurrences for some not recognized countries (unknown id or name whatever)
- "All" (regarding to each country) - which should count occurrences within country

Comment: @Roman Can you please post a new question with your requirements?

Comment: OK, done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360976/how-to-select-on-table-and-count-occurrences-some-values