# How to select on table and count occurrences some values

Tags: sql, jpa, join, count, oracle11g

I am asking you for a help because I do not know SQL very well.

I need to count occurrences some values from table column to achieve effect like statistics table which will look like at the picture below:

### Needed result:

[image]

### Comment:

My Result Table needs to have first two columns (contry and site) comes from first table "Violations" and next 5 columns which will contain numbers (count) of occurrences status_id in "Violations" in each of possible values of id from Status table.

### Explanation:

So, I have existing two tables: Violations and Status. Please look at my [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb466/1/0)

Violations:

- id long,
- country varchar(20),
- site varchar(20),
- status_id long, <-- this is the id of status in Status table.
- ... other columns not important in this case

Status:

- id long,
- status long 
  Column "status" have values (1-4) which are mapped to string values: Suspected Violation (1), Confirmed Violation (2), Confirmed No Violation (3), Not Determined (4)

In result of my join (or based only on one table Violations) is to have table which should contain columns:

- from Violations table: "Country" and "Site"
- from Status table: "Suspected Violation", "Confirmed Violation", "Confirmed No Violation", "Not Determined", "Total" (where this columns are counters of occurrences in Violation table).

### Current Status and new Requirements:

First try is done (thanks to bluefeet) below and is almost perfect...

```
select v.country,
v.site,
    SUM(case when s.id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(case when s.id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(case when s.id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(case when s.id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total
from violations v
inner join status s
    on v.status_id = s.id
group by v.country, v.site
```

or without JOIN:

```
select v.country,
v.site,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(case when v.status_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total
from violations v
group by v.country, v.site
```

...but is not including 3 issues as you can see in the picture which should be. I mean:

- "- All -" which should count occurrences for all countries
- "- Unknown -" which should count occurrences for some not recognized countries
- "- All -" (regarding to each country) - which should count occurrences within one country

### Additional Explanation:

- `-Unknown-` meaning:

Unknown should count occurrences for countries which for example do not exists in DB Country table or have a wrong name/id and that's why is treated here as `Unknown` (I forgot mention that there is table `Country` in DB). 
The same for sites, `Unknown` for sites means that someone put wrong value in Violations.status_id not from range (1-4) because these are only acceptable values existing in Status table.

- We can assume that table Country looks like:

Country:

- id long,
- name varchar(30)

Please help me to write correct sql query which would include these 3 conditions, because I have a big problem to do that.

Comment: How do you specify `Unknown` countries/sites?

Comment: can you confirm what database you are using?

Comment: `Unknown` should count occurrences for countries which for example do not exists in DB Country table or have a wrong name/id and that's why is treated here as Unknown (I forgot mention that there is table Country in DB). The same for sites, `Unknown` for sites means that someone put wrong value in Violations.status_id not from range (1-4) because these are only acceptable values existing in Status table.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g DB

Comment: @Roman How much **time** did u gave t to just write and explain the **Question**? :P I appreciate your **Effort**

Comment: I've wanted to make this Question as much clear as I can :)

Comment: Both answers are correct but i can choose only one so I've chosen one with 'Unknown' issue although answer with rollup is much simpler but without 'Unknown'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***All*** case can be easily done using `UNION` statement (see [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb466/23) for results):

```
(SELECT v.country,
    v.site,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
    0  'isAll'
FROM violations v
GROUP BY v.country, v.site)
union(
SELECT v.country,
    '- All -',
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  'isAll'
FROM violations v
GROUP BY v.country)
UNION (
SELECT '- All -',
    '- All -',
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  'isAll'
FROM violations v)
ORDER BY country, isAll DESC, site
```

However, the performance may not be really great with that kind of query, so I'm not saying it's the best possible solution - but it works.

***Version with 'Unknow'***

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abfb7/21

```
(SELECT IF(c.name IS NULL, '- Unknow -', c.name) as name,
    v.site,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
    0  'isAll'
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country
GROUP BY c.name, v.site)
union(
SELECT IF(c.name IS NULL, '- Unknow -', c.name) as name,
    '- All -',
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  'isAll'
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country
GROUP BY c.name)
UNION (
SELECT '- All -',
    '- All -',
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_SuspectedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.status_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_NotDetermined,
    COUNT(*) Total,
  1  'isAll'
FROM violations v LEFT JOIN country c ON c.name = v.country)
ORDER BY name, isAll DESC, site
```

Comment: @MarcinJaraszek Your solution is adjusted to my requirements, but how to include `Unknown` for countries and sites?

Comment: Could you extend your fiddle with Country table and connection between it and existing ones?

Comment: Yeap, sql fiddle extended. Unfortunatelly in my source DB the country column in Violations is also string value.

Comment: second issue is that this sql is not acceptable in Oracle ;/ errors appears arround: `0 'isAll'` statement. Even after remove it at all it is not compiled: LOG: "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Comment: You're great Marcin, it works nice! Sorry for inconvenience but I was not familiar with sql fiddle earlier. Do you have suspicion why it is not compiled in Oracle? here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c94/1

Comment: Could you explain for what reson is used 'isAll' and is it neccessary?

Comment: It's used to get elements in correct order (`All` as a first item within every country).

Answer (score 0):

Using `with rollup` you will get the needed sum field which you want

```
select v.country,
v.site,
SUM(case when s.id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Total_SuspectedViolations,
SUM(case when s.id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedViolations,
SUM(case when s.id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Total_ConfirmedNoViolations,
SUM(case when s.id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Total_NotDetermined,
COUNT(*) Total
from violations v
     inner join status s
     on v.status_id = s.id
group by v.country, v.site WITH ROLLUP
```

Hope this helps

**[REFER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)** for `with rollup` documentation

[**FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb466/21)

Comment: Nice, but how to include `Unknown` for countries and sites?

Comment: Pl provide some sample records for the unknown type Im unable to get

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abfb7/1/0 Here is updated sqlfiddle with country table and two samples with incorrect values (wrong country and site)